# Pulling JSON Data from API to Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, callout

I am fairly inexperienced at this sort of thing so trying to hack something together from guides and naturally getting stuck when I don't understand the concepts very well.

Anyway I am trying to query the SHipstation API for Shipments (https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/shipments/list/) this contains a nested JSON response.  I have written the following Apex Class to callout to the API and this is working (I have an intention to switch this to namedCredentials but I haven't got that sample working yet):

**APEX Class**

```
public with sharing class ShipstationAPI {

@AuraEnabled
public static Map < String, Object > getCalloutResponseContents(String url) { 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    
    // Because we didn't set the endpoint as a named credential, 
    // our code has to specify:
    // - The required username and password to access the endpoint
    // - The header and header information
     
    String username = 'BLAHBLAH';
    String password = 'BLAHBLAH';
      
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
    EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
       
    // Create a new http object to send the request object
    // A response object is generated as a result of the request  
      
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    //System.debug(res.getBody());
    if(res.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(res.getBody());
    }
    
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    Map < String,
    Object > resultsMap = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    system.debug('resultsMap-->' + resultsMap);

    return resultsMap;
}
}
```

I can tell this is working based on the logs.  Next I have the lightning component which I am very new to and struggling with.  I've created the basic outline with:

**Component**

```
<aura:component  controller="ShipstationAPI" access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" > 

<aura:attribute name="orderID" type="String" default="" />
<aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="response" type="Map"/>
<aura:attribute name="ListOfShipments" type="String[]"/>

<lightning:card iconName="standard:contact" title="Get Tracking:">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="8" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:input aura:id="OrderID" label="Order ID" type="string" value="{!v.orderID}"/>
                <lightning:button label="Get Tracking" onclick="{!c.calloutCtrl }" variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider"> OrderID : {!v.response.shipments.orderNumber}</h3>
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider"> Shipment : {!v.response.shipments.trackingNumber}</h3>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfShipments}" var="shipLst">
            <li>{!shipLst}</li>
        </aura:iteration>
        <p>{!v.message}</p>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
calloutCtrl : function(component, event, helper) {
    var orderID = component.find("OrderID").get("v.value");
    helper.getResponse(component, orderID);
},

})
```

And, finally the bit where all the problems are I expect:

**JS Helper**

```
    ({
    getResponse: function(component, orderID) {
        // create a server side action.       
        var action = component.get("c.getCalloutResponseContents");
        // set the url parameter for getCalloutResponseContents method (to use as endPoint) 
        action.setParams({
            "url": 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments?orderNumber=' + orderID
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                // set the response(return Map<String,object>) to response attribute.      
                component.set("v.response", response.getReturnValue());
                // get the all rates from map by using key              
                var getTracking = component.get("v.response");
                var trackingList = [];
                // play a loop on shipment object 
                for (var key in getTracking) {
variable.        
                    ListOfShipments.push(key + ' = ' + getTracking[key]); 
                }
                // set the ListOfShipments to ListOfShipments attribute on component.           
                component.set("v.ListOfShipments", ListOfShipments);
                console.log("test: "+component.get("v.ListOfShipments")["OrderNumber"]);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
     })
```

I've tried quite a few things but I suspect I shouldn't be using the Map in the Apex Class and pretty much anything in the if block for SUCCESS is wrong...!

Any help is greatly appreciated, considering this is shipstation I was hoping someone else had tried something similar - I'm trying to speed up agents time by reducing the switching between browser tabs/apps.

Final intention is to have it as a widget in the console bottom left but I have to figure out the testing once i get it working :D.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a map, You can convert it to wrapper class. I have used https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ to convert the sample response from https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/shipments/list/ into apex wrapper.

It looks like below:-

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public List<Shipments> shipments;
    public Integer total;
    public Integer page;
    public Integer pages;

    public class InsuranceOptions {
        public Object provider;
        public Boolean insureShipment;
        public Integer insuredValue;
    }

    public class ShipTo {
        public String name;
        public String company;
        public String street1;
        public String street2;
        public Object street3;
        public String city;
        public String state;
        public String postalCode;
        public String country;
        public String phone;
        public Object residential;
    }

    public class Weight {
        public Integer value;
        public String units;
    }

    public class ShipmentItems {
        public Integer orderItemId;
        public Object lineItemKey;
        public String sku;
        public String name;
        public Object imageUrl;
        public Object weight;
        public Integer quantity;
        public Integer unitPrice;
        public Object warehouseLocation;
        public Object options;
        public Integer productId;
        public Object fulfillmentSku;
    }

    public class Shipments {
        public Integer shipmentId;
        public Integer orderId;
        public String orderKey;
        public String userId;
        public String orderNumber;
        public String createDate;
        public String shipDate;
        public Double shipmentCost;
        public Integer insuranceCost;
        public String trackingNumber;
        public Boolean isReturnLabel;
        public String batchNumber;
        public String carrierCode;
        public String serviceCode;
        public String packageCode;
        public String confirmation;
        public Integer warehouseId;
        public Boolean voided;
        public Object voidDate;
        public Boolean marketplaceNotified;
        public Object notifyErrorMessage;
        public ShipTo shipTo;
        public Weight weight;
        public Object dimensions;
        public InsuranceOptions insuranceOptions;
        public Object advancedOptions;
        public List<ShipmentItems> shipmentItems;
        public Object labelData;
        public Object formData;
    }

    
    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

The advantage is access the properties with their name in your lightning component. It saves you a lot of complexity while displaying the value in ui. For example, I can show the response as below:-

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.response}" var="res">
    <aura:iteration items="{!res.shipments}" var="ship">
        {!ship.orderItemId}, {!ship.lineItemKey}
         <!--you can customize according to your requirements-->
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go now.  I think i need to google a bit more just to understand class scope etc.

Comment: Ran out of brain power, I have the console now outputting a value (Yeah!) but it was sheet luck.  I created a new calss for the JSON2Apex, corrected the errors or removed the fields I was unsure about - this appears successful in my tests.  I am simply struggling with how to pass the data to the component.  I have tried adding it to a list without success (only passes 1 value really) and am going back to watch some youtube videos on it now.  Your component looks spot on but I am clearly passing the wrong data from the apex class in the response. I assume i need the whole object.